# Exporting environment variables in `.profile` with a bash and-list construct

Tags: bash, environment-variables, profile, dot-files, login-manager

I am using gdm3 as my login manager. Upon login, all the `PATH` modifications in my `.profile` are set and exported correctly. For example, lines like these below work fine:

```
if [ -d "$HOME/bin" ] ; then
    PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"
fi

if [ -d "$HOME/.local/bin" ] ; then
    PATH="$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH"
fi
```

However, line below doesn't work as expected:

```
# Use colors for less, man, etc.
[[ -f ~/.LESS_TERMCAP ]] && . ~/.LESS_TERMCAP
```

The file `~/.LESS_TERMCAP` just contains a bunch of `export` statements. Interestingly, if I start up my terminal and type `. .profile`, then `~/.LESS_TERMCAP` does get sourced. Why isn't that happening at startup? I come across many dot files that include such 'and list' constructs, so I am a bit confused. Thank you for all the help.

**UPDATE**:

As noted in the comments by @fra-san, part of the issue is resolved by noting that the display manager runs `dash` instead of `bash`, and replacing `[[` with appropriate test constructs. However, I am still perplexed by the following situation: the file `~/.LESS_TERMCAP` is not sourced, even though `PROFILE_VARIABLE` is set. `~/.LESS_TERMCAP` contains the following:

```
export LESS_TERMCAP_mb=$'\e[1;32m'
export LESS_TERMCAP_md=$'\e[1;32m'
export LESS_TERMCAP_me=$'\e[0m'
export LESS_TERMCAP_se=$'\e[0m'
export LESS_TERMCAP_so=$'\e[01;33m'
export LESS_TERMCAP_ue=$'\e[0m'
export LESS_TERMCAP_us=$'\e[1;4;31m'
```

However, running `. ~/.profile` does bring color to man pages.
I am on Debian Sid, running gdm3 and i3. Please let me know any additional info I can provide.

Comment: `[[` is Bash-specific, can you replace it with the regular `if [` like in lines above?

Comment: I changed `[[ -f ~/.LESS_TERMCAP ]] && . ~/.LESS_TERMCAP` to `[ -f ~/.LESS_TERMCAP ] && . ~/.LESS_TERMCAP`, but now upon reboot instead of color, I see weird control characters in man pages.

Comment: I just changed `[ -f ~/.LESS_TERMCAP ] && . ~/.LESS_TERMCAP` to `[ -f ~/.LESS_TERMCAP ] && source ~/.LESS_TERMCAP` and rebooted again, and this time I don't see the weird control characters but there is no color in the man pages either. However, sourcing the `.profile` manually brings color to the man pages.

Comment: The issue in your question seems to be solved by noting that your display manager uses a POSIX shell (i.e. no support for `[[`) to source your `.profile`. The issue in your comments seems to be unrelated to the first one and you should probably ask a new question (or reword this one if you are not looking for an answer to it anymore). It _may_ be useful to know which operating system (and version) you are using and, possibly, see the relevant parts of the sourced files (though I wouldn't know for sure).

Comment: Do you also have a `~/.bash_profile` file?

Comment: @Kusalananda: yes, but it is not sourced upon login from what I can tell. However, it doesn't contain anything except two lines to source `.bashrc` and `.profile`. 
@fra-san: updated the question, thank you.